# Pandas does not convert NaN to None properly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

#### Environment

- Python 3.9.6
- numpy 1.21.0
- pandas 1.3.1

#### What I'm trying to do

Replace all the `NaN` values in a dataframe with `None`

#### What I have now

```
In[6]: import pandas as pd
In[7]: import numpy as np
In[8]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,np.nan],"b":[np.nan,"foo"]})
In[9]: df
Out[9]: 
     a    b
0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  foo


In[10]: pd.notnull(df)
Out[10]: 
       a      b
0   True  False
1  False   True


In[11]: df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
Out[11]: 
     a     b
0  1.0  None
1  NaN   foo
```

#### Expected Output

```
In[11]: df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
Out[11]: 
     a     b
0  1.0  None
1  None  foo
```

I have tested this on another machine with Python 3.8.5 and pandas==1.1.1, and it worked as expected. Is this a bug?

Thank you!

Comment: Doubt this would be considered a bug, pandas will cast to avoid setting the float column to an object column, so `None` is coerced to the float `nan`, while in the second object column, it doesn't care and will use `None`.

Comment: I don't know why you need `None`, rather than `nan`, but you can force the cast yourself using `df.astype(object).where(pd.notnull(df), None)`

Comment: @user3483203 I used to convert dataframe to json response using `df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)` (since json doesn't accept `nan`). After updating the package version, my server suddenly started complaining about `nan` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug.  In fact, the result you are seeing in `pandas==1.1.1` is a bug, that has been fixed in later versions by [PR39761](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/39761).

The fix is also mentioned in the [1.3.0 release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#other).

In general, `pandas` will try to cast to avoid results that contain `object` dtype columns, and this is no exception.  If you would like to force the cast, you can use:

```
>>> df.astype(object).where(pd.notnull(df), None)
      a     b
0   1.0  None
1  None   foo
```

It seems as though there has been some grumbling in the community about this bug-fix, discussed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42423).